# Simple app.map() not working MVC core

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core

In Startup.cs i have a extremely simple Map

```
app.Map("/Home",x=>x.UseMiddlewareLogic1() );
```

My full code of Configure looks as shown below

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("/Home",x=>x.UseMiddlewareLogic1() );
            //app.UseMiddlewareLogic1();
            //app.UseMiddlewareLogic2();
            app.Run(async context =>
             Logic3(context));
        }
```

Logic 3 is just a response write as shown below

```
 public async Task Logic3(HttpContext obj)
        {
            await obj.Response.WriteAsync("Logic 3\n");

        }
```

The above code shows 404 not found. 
The middleware logic class is the standard class which comes in the visual studio template. I am using VS 2017.

```
 public class MiddlewareLogic1
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public MiddlewareLogic1(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("This is logic123 \n");
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class MiddlewareLogic1Extensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMiddlewareLogic1(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<MiddlewareLogic1>();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have anything else in your `Configure` method? Specifically, _after_ the `app.Map(...)`?

Comment: yes i do have app.run ( updated code for it) where i am writing the final output to response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem: `app.Map("/Home",x=>x.UseMiddlewareLogic1() );`.

If you are using `app.Map`, the framework will not execute middlewares outside `Map` branch (that are registered after `app.Map` - order of middleware is important). Instead, it will automatically terminate that. In other words, you never need use `.Run` inside `.Map` to terminate the pipeline.

And you get 404 as there is `await _next(httpContext);` in your `MiddlewareLogic1` middleware used in `Map`, but there are no other pipelines registered in this `Map` branch.
If you remove `await _next(httpContext);` you will see in response `"This is logic123` instead of 404.

---

**Update**: both `.Map` and `.MapThen` have the same terminating behavior. As a solution, you may consider to 
- replace `.Map` to `.Use` and do query comparing login internally. 
- Or register a separate chain of middlewares in `.app.Map`.

Comment: The above articles looks very much basic. It does not answer my question.

when i put this app.MapWhen(context => 
            context.Request.QueryString.Value.StartsWith("/home123"), 
                x => x.UseMiddlewareLogic1());
Only Logic3 executes.

Comment: But yes i can understand the middleware standard code is created for simple scenarios so will not work for this. I will need to amend it.

Comment: Yes they both have terminating behavior. can you update your answer i will mark it thanks.

Comment: +1 from me. The tip about .Map, MapThen (and MapWhen) having the same terminating behavior resolved my issue. Conditional checks are best injected into the pipeline with app.UseWhen which branches and joins back to the main request pipeline.